# Why does a problem fact change that changes problem fact properties cause corruption?

Tags: optaplanner

> The entity (...)'s shadow variable (...)'s corrupted value (...) changed to uncorrupted value (...) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.

I've encountered the above corruption message for various reasons and for many occurrences in the past while developing our application. For all those times they were caused by real issues. However, this time I believe the justification of the cause, if any, is not so clear.

This corruption occurred after a problem fact change was processed. Here's the log:

```
1. Solving started: time spent (3), best score (-3init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
2.     CH step (0), time spent (10), score (-2init/0hard/9180soft), selected move count (1), picked move (B[7] {null -> SS[7]}).
3.     CH step (1), time spent (13), score (-1init/0hard/18360soft), selected move count (1), picked move (B[8] {null -> SS[7]}).
4.     CH step (2), time spent (17), score (0hard/27540soft), selected move count (1), picked move (B[9] {null -> SS[7]}).
5. Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (18), best score (0hard/27540soft), score calculation speed (5666/sec), step total (3).
6.     Step index (0), new score (0hard/27540soft) for real-time problem fact change.
7. Real-time problem fact changes done: step total (1), new best score (0hard/27540soft).
8. Terminating solver early.
9. java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption after completedAction (Initial score calculated):
       (...)
       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:542) ~[optaplanner-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.recaller.BestSolutionRecaller.solvingStarted(BestSolutionRecaller.java:83) ~[optaplanner-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:76) ~[optaplanner-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:210) ~[optaplanner-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:190) ~[optaplanner-core-7.29.0.Final.jar:7.29.0.Final]
       at com.mloho.es.df.engine.opt.planner.common.solver.SolverEngine.lambda$solveAsync$0(SolverEngine.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Lines 5 - 7 all report the same score even though the property of a problem fact was changed during the problem fact change. If the solution were to be refreshed (all variable listeners triggered) then the score of the solution as well as the values of several custom shadow variables would have changed.

It makes sense that during solving (CH and LS phases for example) we wouldn't expect any of the problem facts to change so therefore we only have to worry about our custom shadow variable's values being updated by our genuine variables. However, after the solving has been halted and a problem fact change has been processed, shouldn't OptaPlanner expect the possiblity that our custom shadow variable's values might have changed and not because of genuine variables but instead because of problem fact property changes?

Speaking more technically: Since none of the problem fact properties are annotated as a derivative of `VariableListenerNotifiable` and therefore won't let the `CustomShadowVariable`s be updated once we do a `scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners()` after doing `beforeProblemPropertyChanged()`s and `afterProblemPropertyChanged()`s, then shouldn't the solution just get refreshed completely before the solving starts again? Refresh in the sense of: `VariableListenerSupport::triggerAllVariableListeners()`

Current timeline based on the log above:
`Solving starts -> CH phase -> Problem Fact Change -> Solver restarts as normal -> Corruption`

Proposed change:
`Solving starts -> CH phase -> Problem Fact Change -> **Refresh solution** -> Solver restarts as normal -> ...`

As a workaround for now I've made it so that for all of my problem fact changes, that change problem fact properties, I execute the following at the end:

```
((VariableListenerSupport) ((AbstractScoreDirector) scoreDirector).getSupplyManager()).triggerAllVariableListeners();
```

instead of the usual:

```
scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
```

Comment: Without a reproducer and doing a deep dive into this issue, it's hard to say.

Comment: The reproducible test case that I'll eventually upload here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1736
will contain the project skeleton.

However, it's a skeleton in that I would've ripped out all of the algorithms, variable listeners custom code, etc... So I'll try to fill in those with words and pseudocode if that helps. Since there's a workaround for this for us now, there's no priority to get it officially fixed so unfortunately this will have to do for now.

Comment: We're looking forward to that reproducer.